Does Rbe is equivalent to Rpi of the small signal PI model?
I have a question about the bipolar transistor model (and behavior) :
I would want to know if the Rbe of the transistor is the equivalent of the Rpi of the small signal Pi model ?
if it's the same, do you know if the Rbe/Rpi is temperature dependent ? if yes, what is the law ?
Thanks for your help

if rbe = vbe/ib then yes rpi is equal to rbe. And rpi is current and temperature dependent.  rpi = Vt/Ib where Vt is a thermal voltage look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_constant#Thermal_voltage And you will see that Vt is temperature dependent Vt = 86.25E-6 * T [in Kelvin].

It's clear, thanks for your reply.

It is even worse ! The temperature dependency of Vt can be neglected (rpi rises with Vt). Much more critical is the dependency of Ib=Ic/B because of Ic=Is[exp(Vbe/Vt)]. It is the current Is which is very temperature-sensitive and leads to the well-known tempco d(Vbe)/d(T)= -2mV/K.
This means: The resistor rpi decreases with temperature.

This is a dynamic, small-signal resistance, determined at a given operating point in the b-e junction. You need to differentiate the I-V curve at a given base current: $r_{\pi}=\frac{dV_{be}}{dI_b}$.
